# Jquery Validation

Tags: jquery

Is there is any way to validate form  using jquery on dynamic fields.

I want to make it required fields

I am creating form fields dynamically using Jsp.

like

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
<input type="text" name="name1" value="">
<input type="text" name="name2" value="">
<input type="text" name="name3" value="">
<input type="text" name="name4" value="">
</form>
```

so on....

I want to validate this form fields with required form field.

Comment: Are you already using the jquery validation plugin, or are looking to get started?

Comment: I am already using jquery validation plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this [jQuery plugin: Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) , its demo and the view source. I think you can also generate this little javascript dynamically with your form fields.

Comment: What kind of answer is this?  The OP already stated he was using the Validation plugin.

Comment: @Sparky672, I guess the hint (to generate javascript dynamically) in my answer has helped OP and may be that is why  it is also marked as answer by OP. If you have got the same question and need some detailed answer, then let me know here and I will add details to the answer.

Comment: That's the whole point of SO.  It's not only about you, me or the OP...  it's about these answers making sense to any future reader.  So yes, if you could please clarify the answer, that would be great and it will earn lots of rep in the future too.

Answer (score 2):

You could "tag" your form element with a class name like "required" in JSP.
Then onSubmit you can check if any $(".required",form) has empty value.